# How to create running total and restart it every time NaN appears?

Tags: python

I want to launch a new running total everytime it runs into nan
For example, from the attached picture it would sum first 3 values `[1242536, 379759, 1622295]` and then show running total `3244590.0`, then it would start new running total from 5th value and till 9th, show sum for these values and so on. I want to place these running total to new column beside these NaN values.

[image: Example]

I have tried to approach this issue the following way :

```
for i in df['Budget_Expenditure_2012_']:
        if np.isnan(i) == True:
            x = pd.Index(df['Budget_Expenditure_2012_']).get_loc(i)

    
print(x)

for item in range(0, len(x) - 1, 2):
    second_list.append([x[item],x[item + 1]])    
print(second_list)
```

The idea would be to find the sum of values between each pair of rows. This pair  would be a start position and last position of each range needed to be sumed.
At this point I got lost as to how I would execute this sum operation.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This site isn't meant for "How do I do this?" questions.  If you've made an attempt and it's not working, then we can help you with that.

Comment: or I see,thank you. I will try to show the way I tried to do.

Comment: not sure though how to hide this question before moderator close it

Comment: There's a "delete" option at the bottom of the question next to "share" and "edit".

Comment: Does this question look better now, or still of poor quality ?

Comment: It is good to post a sample of the data as text so everybody can replicate the code. To write all those numbers seems like a annoying task.

Comment: Thank you for advise, I will take it as practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `shift`, `isna` and `cumsum` to `gropuby`, then `transform` and finally assign the resulting values where the column is `nan`

```
df.loc[df['Budget_Expenditure_2012_'].isna(), 'new_column'] = (
    df.groupby(
        df.Budget_Expenditure_2012_.shift()
                                   .isna()
                                   .cumsum()
    )['Budget_Expenditure_2012_'].transform('sum')
)
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand how this code works ?  So you select ['Budget_Expenditure_2012_']  but specifically where it is nan, then you choose a ['new column'] to place the result. You use groupby.transform to turn groupby object into series. Inside groupby you shift rows 1 below, why ?  then you check for nan and turn it to  boolean and then somehow cumulatively sum original values. how does it work XD

Comment: Just do it step by step, so first a `shift` the reason for the shift is to have first value as `NaN` and then the rest of the values its just a preprocessing step. Then a `isna` with the `cumsum` this will basically assign a unique integer to the rows that share the same group, that way you can do a `groupby`. After the `groupby`, you do a `transform('sum')` this will do the sum of the group but return a series with the same indexes as the input data, that way you can assign this output a new variable, in this case, `new_column`. Again just try to do it step by step.

Comment: Just quick update, if you don't do the shift, then your groups will be shifted in the output, try doing it without the `shift` so you can spot the difference.

Comment: thank you a lot for explanation, I learnt a cool trick

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can get the 'running totals' upto each nan on a new column called 'Totals'.

```
total = 0
df['Totals'] = 0 # assign 0 initially to all rows of the new column

for i in range(df.shape[0]): # shape[0] return number of rows

    expenditure = df.loc[i+1, 'Budget_Expenditure_2012_'] # i+1 coz your indexing starts at 1

    if np.isnan(expenditure):
        df.loc[i, 'Totals'] = total
        total = 0
    else:
        total += expenditure
```

Comment: would be a great help if it appeared in new column, trying to check this code right now

Comment: if np.isnan(i): ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''. This is what I get , when I try to use your solution, trying to investigate into issue

Comment: Yes, I've updated the code. It comes in a new column called 'Totals' beside the corresponding nan values

Comment: Are you sure it's a float? and not a string? Can you do type(df.loc[4, 'Budget_Expenditure_2012_'])

Comment: I am pretty sure it is float, I used df['Budget_Expenditure_2012_'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Budget_Expenditure_2012_'], downcast="float") before my code. I just tried to check the type and it shows KeyError: 0 without clear explanation (very long error log)

Comment: wonder if it has something to do with environment or something around that

Comment: I'm sorry use 4 not i, when checking type